# PHP|BCMath: How to get bcscale value?

Tags: php, scale, bcmath

How do I get the scale set in BCMath's bcscale() method?

Example:

```
bcscale(25);
```

How do I get the 25?
Thanks!

Comment: Hi do you need to javascript or else PHP ?

Comment: @VIVEK-MDU AS you can see from the title and the tags I'm refering to PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in PHP 7.3.

Calling `bcscale(10)` will return the previous scale and calling `bcscale()` will return the current scale.

[source](https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/2739)

Answer (score 8):

**Update:** [As of PHP 7.3.0](https://www.php.net/ChangeLog-7.php#7.3.0) you can just call the `bcscale()` function with no argument:

```
var_dump(bcscale()); // int(25)
```

---

Prior to PHP 7.3.0 you could at first try to read the `bcmath.scale` INI setting, which defaults to 0:

```
$scale = ini_get('bcmath.scale');
```

Since calling `bcscale()` didn't change the `bcmath.scale` INI setting, the only way to get the current scale factor was using a workaround like that:

```
$scale = strlen(bcsqrt('2')) - 2;
var_dump($scale); // int(25)
```